# Stability of equilibrium in autonomous first order DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $\dot{x} = f(x)$ has an equilibrium $x^{\ast}$ such that $f(x^{\ast})=0$, that equilibrium is stable if $f'(x^{\ast}) < 0$, or unstable if $f'(x^{\ast}) > 0$, according to [Theorem 3.2.1 here](https://books.google.com/books?id=kKRyws2x9tQC&pg=PA63). Where can I find a proof of this result? Also, is it a special case of a more general theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, there is a more general theorem of this, sometimes named 'Liapunov's indirect method' and it says the following:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $C^1$ vector field and $x^*$ an equilibrium of the system $\dot x = f(x)$.
>
> - If every eigenvalue of $\text{D}f(x^*)$ has negative real part then $x^*$ is asymptotically stable (in particular stable).
> - If one eigenvalue of $\text{D}f(x^*)$ has positive real part then $x^*$ is unstable.

In your case we have the 1D-case i.e.  $\text{D}f(x^*)=f'(x^*)$ ($\text{D}$ indicates the Jacobian). A proof of this should be found in every (mathematical) Dynamical Systems book, in particular I am thinking of the books by Wiggins and Guckenheimer and Hirsch/Smale. I can look this up later for you if you are interested.

Comment: Thank you very much. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe it is [this theorem](https://books.google.com/books?id=UG4Rh4OG-hUC&pg=PA187) in Hirsch/Smale. Also, [Theorem 2 and 3](https://books.google.com/books?id=VFnSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA130) in Perko, right?

Comment: @Durden Yes, looks good. Also here (Theorem 1.2.5) in the book by Wiggins https://books.google.de/books?id=YhXnBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PR3&hl=de&pg=PA11#v=onepage&q&f=false and it is also proven there.